# Fedora 20 ACPI issues on black screen before log on

Tags: fedora, linux-kernel, 64bit, acpi

I installed Fedora 20 64-bit with the standard Gnome3 desktop environment and while booting a black screen is displayed with 4 messages in the following form:

```
Failed to find handle for ACPI object
```

My computer is Dell Latitude E5440 and there are issues with the touchpad as well, I state this since it may be related with the issue I experience. The screenshot below illustrates my point; I am not that an experienced Linux power user so I would appreciate some guidance.

**EDIT**

I found out that this problem does not occur with Linux kernel version `3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64`, but it occurs in the kernels `3.16.2-201.fc20.x86-64` and `3.16.6-200.fc20.x86-64`. Is this situation not weird considering that an older kernel works better?

[image]

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your video card. Do you have an NVidia graphics card in this systems?

Comment: @slm I do not have a dedicated GPU as far as I know on this particular laptop. There may be an Intel HD series card, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue sounds like a bug in the kernel to me. I found this bugzilla issue titled: [Bug 42696 - Wrong ACPI handle is being detected for NVIDIA graphics card on Lenovo Ideapad Y470/Y570](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42696).

*excerpt*

> On the Lenovo Ideapad Y470 and Lenovo Ideapad Y570, the kernel assigns
>   the _SB.PCI0.PEG0.VGA handle to the PCI device (possibly because the
>   _DOS method is found on the handle?)
>
> However, the correct _DSM, _ROM, _PS0 and _PS3 can be found on the 
>   _SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP handle. _PSx on the VGA handle is basically a
>   no-op, it only gets/sets the _PSC variable. _ROM does not exist and
>   the _DSM method is not useful comparing it to the PEGP._DSM method.
>
> Due to this issue, the nouveau driver fails to load the vbios (because
>   _ROM does not exist on VGA). Similarly, the proprietary nvidia driver fails to load. As for the _PS0 and _PS0 methods, using the
>   pci_set_power_state methods does not really disable the PCI device.

There was a patch for this but it may not of fixed the issue on all hardware.

#### Actions to take

1. I'd add your system to the list of systems in the bug if it's not already there
2. Download and try another distro to confirm that it isn't a hardware issue, and also to see if the issue lingers with a different distro

#### EDIT #1

Researching your problem a bit more the issue seems to be stemming from DMAR/IOMMU.

*excerpt - [Decoding the DMAR tables in ACPI...IOMMU Part 2](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/09/11/decoding-the-dmar-tables-in-acpiiommu-part-2)*

> DMAR - indicates the DMA remapping unit responsible for doing the
>   translation. Also called IOMMU affectionately. There can be more than
>   1 hardware unit in a system. Each can control a set of devices. For
>   performance reasons you might find in a desktop system, there can be
>   one just for the high definition audio engine so it can enjoy being
>   the only child.

It would seem that it's having an issue in extracting ACPI information from your system while booting. I did track down the above error message to this particular patch to the iommu component:

- [[PATCH 05/33] iommu/vt-d: Add ACPI devices into dmaru->devices[] array](http://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/iommu/2014-March/007989.html).

This system is a bit dated, I found that certain configurations of this laptop are in fact [certified by Canonical to run Ubuntu (12.04)](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201307-13941/). Without knowing the exact configuration of your system, it's almost impossible to debug it any further.

Now given that it's certified for a particular version of Ubuntu, you could try installing that version, purely to confirm if the system is having a hardware issue or if there have been changes made to either the Linux kernel and/or driver(s) in newer versions, which are rendering it not compatible with your system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I remedy the situation or will it pose a problem if I continue using it as it is?

Comment: @Vesnog - seems like it's an identification issue, if the system works fine, otherwise then I'd ignore it for the time being.

Comment: Unfortunately, I noticed that the system hangs after I try to reboot it displaying the same messages as seen on the screenshot I uploaded. Apart from that my video card is one from Intel HD series. I think it is HD4400  but I am not sure of it as these specifications may change depending on the country the product is shipped.

Comment: @Vesnog - background about what dmar is: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/09/11/decoding-the-dmar-tables-in-acpiiommu-part-2

Comment: I will look into it thanks maybe the problem might be solved.

Comment: Please take a look at the updated question. On a different kernel the problem was non-existent.

Comment: @Vesnog - I've seen issues before with newer kernels that were non-existent in previous ones. There are a variety of ways that this can occur. There are typically a block of patches that are applied to Fedora/RH only kernels that haven't worked their way upstream as yet. I would file this as a bug with Fedora/RH via Bugzilla since they're probably better equipped to get you an ultimate fix. You could also try going up the kernel versions that are available and see if you can narrow down which one started exhibiting the problem.

Comment: @Vesnog - I would take a multi-pronged approach to this and do everything,if I wanted to resolve it. That is, file a bug,look through the commit logs for the official Fedora/RH kernels, and attempt to use the various kernel revisions to target the point where things break.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I am a bit unfamiliar with these topics I want to resolve this issue for good, though. I think I should start with filing a bug, how can I do that? By the way how can I make use of another kernel that is not in the GRUB2 menu, should I install, download it somehow?

Comment: Bug filing is covered here: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Bugzilla. Other kernel's are available via `yum install ...`. But if you do not know how to do this then you'll probably don't want do this, it's a bit complicated a task then, if you're not sure how to proceed.